# HTML - Determine type of href link is page or file and open appropriately

Tags: html, anchor, href

I have some data stored in the database with the following:

```
Click <a href="http://someweb.com/default.html">here please</a>
```

and

```
Click <a href="http://someweb.com/somedocument.docx">here to open me please</a>
```

When the data is loaded from the database and the markup constructed for this in code, target="_blank" is appended to the anchor - a.

That works well with the page links, however when you open the document it opens it in a new window.

Is there a nice way to distinguish the different between a page and a file rather than coding the obvious - if href ends with ".docx" and every other extension known to man?

The backend is coded in C#.  The following is used to append the target attribute:

```
HyperLink myhlink = new HyperLink();

string pattern = @"(?<start><a[^>]*)(?<end>>)";
string repl = @"${start} target=""_blank"" ${end}";
string newString = Regex.Replace(myhlink.Text, pattern, repl);
myhlink.Text = newString;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible unfortunately. A web server is at liberty to output anything in theory, regardless of the URL. You can't determine the content type unless you actually make the request to the server yourself, and even then it's a dynamic response that could change any time and depends on your cookies plus any other number of variables.

The best you can do is what you suggest - use a regex and try to guess what might be a file using common prefixes. You could look at [Mime types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) and default suffixes for those which various MIME libraries provide. Web servers also use these libraries to guess what kind of content type to declare it as, so it's a good guess at least.